# Use XAML StringFormat to get one decimal place

Tags: wpf, slider, shapes

I have this `Circle Slider`:

[image]

And this is my `TextBlock` inside:

```
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=knobSlider}" Foreground="White"
                   FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.7,2.478" Margin="59,100,44,26" Width="47" />
```

How can i convert the `Slider` `value` from double to only one decimal place and put this text in the middle of the circle ?

Comment: You can use Binding String Format (StringFormat={}{0:#,#.0}). https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What are you using for a Circle Slider, and can you post the XAML for it?

Comment: i am using it instead of the default one, you can find all the example here: https://alala666888.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/a-knob-slider-control/

Comment: A beautiful control in WPF, for once...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the string format `<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.0}}" />`.

So in your case it would look like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=knobSlider, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.0}}" Foreground="White"
               FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.7,2.478" Margin="59,100,44,26" Width="47" />
```

Comment: And how can i put my Text Block in the middle of the circle ? (both my slider and my text block are inside grid)

Comment: Well it's a different question and we'd need more details on how your grid is structured, but normally you play with the column/row sizes or padding/margin.